# jQuery popup won't work in IE11 Enterprise mode

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a classic asp application which runs on the IE 11 Enterprise mode, where I added the jQuery popup with some search function on it. This functionality works properly with Normal mode but not with Enterprise mode(search functionality and CSS for popup to look decent). Anybody knows the reason?

I have added the below libraries.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/lib/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/lib/chosen_v1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And there are tow other JavaScript file which is related to the popup functionality.

The page is a part of the iframe and iframe contain the above changes.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Classic ASP? Really?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and below are the changes.

```
<!doctype html>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11">
```